# How to change the font in fabric-ui

Tags: office-ui-fabric

Just adding a `className` to a tag doesn't help

```
                        <p className="ms-font-m">
                            sometext
                        </p>
```

doesn't change the font

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/styles/typography

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the Fabric Core CSS classes directly, rather than with CSS-in-JS, you'll need to include the CSS on your page following the instructions for [getting started with Fabric Core](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/get-started/web#fabric-core):

1. Add a reference to the stylesheet in the `<head>` of your page. Simplest way is to use the copy on Microsoft's CDN (grab the URL directly from the docs linked above to get the latest version):

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://static2.sharepointonline.com/files/fabric/office-ui-fabric-core/10.0.0/css/fabric.min.css">`

2. Add the `ms-Fabric` class to a containing element, such as `<body>`, to set the font-family. Then you can use the other classes to set sizes and colors:

```
<body class="ms-Fabric">
  <span class="ms-font-su ms-fontColor-themePrimary">Big blue text</span>
</body>
```

Comment: I thought css-in-js is the recommended way to do css. Can you comment on that please? Will you support both? Thank you

Comment: css-in-js is recommended, but if you want to use CSS class names, this is how to do it. I'm not sure offhand what the plans are for continuing to support both.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what' I was looking for but here is one way to do it:

https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react/blob/86337324a5fd8b522855eb8bdcbf012a868a26ba/packages/styling/README.md#using-fabric-core-classes

```
import {
  ColorClassNames,
  FontClassNames
} from '@uifabric/styling';

function renderHtml() {
  return (
    `<div class="${ [
      ColorClassNames.themePrimary,
      FontClassNamed.medium
      ].join(' ') }">Hello world!</div>`
  );
}
```

my understanding per https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react/wiki/Component-Styling#styling-best-practices  is that I need to use `getTheme()` and `styles` (not `style`) prop function for the new way of doing styling. So I'm still looking for a `getTheme()` solution

==============

here is the list of available fonts

https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react/blob/1b9405b3b64839975e16ee1fad04d7868d9e3b99/packages/styling/src/styles/fonts.ts

fonts visualized: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/styles/typography

colors: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/styles/colors

Comment: Did you find a suitable way to change the default font using css-in-js? I would like to swap the default Segoe font to Arial.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by adding the following code when loading theme:

loadTheme({
defaultFontStyle: { fontFamily: 'Comic Sans MS', fontWeight: 'bold' },
.......
This is available since version 7.21.0 of office-ui-fabric-react

These are the urls where you can find the release and report of bug:
https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui/issues/7416
https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui/releases/tag/office-ui-fabric-react_v7.21.0
https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui/pull/9981